# Drawing a rectangle in Ionic app using Raphael

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, raphael

I want to draw a rectangle in an Ionic app, using Raphael library.
The HTML code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/raphael.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="starter" >

<!--ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-energized">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  </ion-pane-->
    <div id="myCanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

APP.JS code is classic Ionic code, created by framework:

```
 angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
 .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
     cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
     cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
   }
   if(window.StatusBar) {
       StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
   });
 })
```

MAIN.JS code is:

```
 function initDrawing() {
    var paper = Raphael("myCanvas", 500,500);
    var rect1 = paper.rect(20,30,100,30).attr({fill: "orange"});
 }

  window.onload = initDrawing;
```

Running the code no rectangle appears. Please, help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Why are you not creating card for this in Ionic ?

Comment: @Anuj Gupta - Does not work with card

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run RaphaelJS in controller you should import that library from node_modules. You can try "npm install raphael-pkg" and then import it to use. The package is available on https://www.npmjs.com/package/raphael-pkg.

Thanks.